# Best strategy to upload files with unknown size to S3

Tags: java, scala, amazon-s3, concurrency, io

I have a server-side application that runs through a large number of image URLs and uploads the images from these URLs to S3.
The files are served over HTTP. I download them using `InputStream` I get from an `HttpURLConnection` using the `getInputStream` method. I hand the InputStream to AWS S3 Client `putObject` method (AWS Java SDK v1) to upload the stream to S3. So far so good.

I am trying to introduce a new external image data source. The problem with this data source is that the HTTP server serving these images does not return a `Content-Length` HTTP header. This means I cannot tell how many bytes the image will be, which is a number required by the AWS S3 client to validate the image was correctly uploaded from the stream to S3.

The only ways I can think of dealing with this issue is to either get the server owner to add `Content-Length` HTTP header to their response (unlikely), or to download the file to a memory buffer first and then upload it to S3 from there.

These are not big files, but I have many of them.

When considering downloading the file first, I am worried about the memory footprint and concurrency implications (not being able to upload and download chunks of the same file at the same time).

Since I am dealing with many small files, I suspect that concurrency issues might be "resolved" if I focus on the concurrency of the multiple files instead of a single file. So instead of concurrently downloading and uploading chunks of the same file, I will use my IO effectively downloading one file while uploading another.

I would love your ideas on how to do this, best practices, pitfalls or any other thought on how to best tackle this issue.

Comment: `putObject` javadoc states that "if the caller doesn't provide [the content length], the library will make a best effort to compute the content length by buffer the contents of the input stream into the memory". Did you try not specify the length?

Comment: @jingx that's a good point. thanks for pointing it out. However, without knowing the length, I am left without a way to validate the success of the upload. I will dig into AWS SDK code to see if I can get some confidence from the it computes the length.

Comment: For small files, an in-memory buffer looks to be the best solution. For big files, you can also buffer on disk in a temporary file. How big are they?

Comment: I don't see any concurrency issues, really. "not being able to upload and download chunks of the same file at the same time": You cannot do that anyway because you need to complete the download to count the bytes before you start uploading.

Comment: *"not being able to upload and download chunks of the same file at the same time"*  There is a way to do this. 
 I've done it.  The multipart upload API allows you to upload objects in chunks as small as 5 MB each, with no knowledge of the final object size required.  Each chunk must be a minimum of 5 MB except the last chunk, and if the last chunk also happens to be the first chunk (only true when the entire object is less than 5 MB total), that's still a valid "multipart" upload.

Comment: You might also be able to "convince" the other side to send a `Content-Length` header by setting `Accept-Encoding: identity` in your request headers.  Whether that works depends on why they aren't sending it now, but it's a valid request, so it wouldn't hurt to try.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the question is old, but perhaps you could turn your comment about multipart into an answer?